# C# Implement derived Types of an Interface Definition?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have an inheritance tree, which looks like this:

`Foo` and `Bar` both have an `Id`, as defined through an specific `Id` class.
The `id` classes itself are derived from a common base class.

I would now like to write an interface which can encompass both `Foo` and `Bar`,
but the compiler does not allow that, I would have to use `BaseId` as the type in `Foo` and `Bar`, but I would like to avoid that.

```
public class BaseId
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
}

public class FooId: BaseId
{}

public class BarId: BaseId
{}

public interface MyInterface
{
    public BaseId Id {get; set; }
}

public class Foo: MyInterface
{
    public FooId Id {get; set;}
}

public class Bar: MyInterface
{
    public BarId Id {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: As already provided in an answer, generics would work well here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generics can help here. First you define interface like this:

```
public interface IMyInterface<out T> where T : BaseId {
    T Id { get; }
}
```

And then you can implement it like this:

```
public class Foo : IMyInterface<FooId> {
    public FooId Id { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : IMyInterface<BarId> {
    public BarId Id { get; set; }
}
```

Achieving your goal to use `BarId` and `FooId` in specific classes.

Both classes are also castable to `IMyInterface<BaseId>` in case you are in situation where you don't know the exact id type:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
// works fine
var asId = (IMyInterface<BaseId>)foo;
```

Comment: Thank you! I have never used the out keyword here, but it's exactly what I needed.